# Split a large json file into multiple smaller files

Tags: python, json, node.js, lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a large JSON file, about 5 million records and a file size of about 32GB, that I need to get loaded into our Snowflake Data Warehouse. I need to get this file broken up into chunks of about 200k records (about 1.25GB) per file. I'd like to do this in either Node.JS or Python for deployment to an AWS Lambda function, unfortunately I haven't coded in either, yet. I have C# and a lot of SQL experience, and learning both node and python are on my to do list, so why not dive right in, right!?

My first question is "Which language would better serve this function? Python, or Node.JS?"

I know I don't want to read this entire JSON file into memory (or even the output *smaller* file). I need to be able to "stream" it in *and* out into the new file based on a record count (200k), properly close up the json objects, and continue into a new file for another 200k, and so on. I know Node can do this, but if Python can also do this, I feel like it would be easier to quickly start using for other ETL stuff I'll be doing soon.

My second question is "Based on your recommendation above, can you also recommend what modules I should require/import to help me get started? Primarily as it relates to not pulling the entire json file into memory? Maybe some tips, tricks, or 'How would you do it's? And if you're feeling really generous, some code example to help push me into the deep end on this?

I can't include a sample of the JSON data, as it contains personal information. But I can provide the JSON schema ...

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "items": {
    "properties": {
      "activities": {
        "properties": {
          "activity_id": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "frontlineorg_id": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "import_id": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "is_source": {
            "items": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "address": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "congress_dist_name": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "congress_dist_number": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "congress_end_yr": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "congress_number": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "congress_start_yr": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "county": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "formatted": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "latitude": {
            "items": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "longitude": {
            "items": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "number": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "observes_dst": {
            "items": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "post_directional": {
            "items": {
              "type": "null"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "pre_directional": {
            "items": {
              "type": "null"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "school_district": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "school_dist_name": {
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "type": "array"
                },
                "school_dist_type": {
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "type": "array"
                },
                "school_grade_high": {
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "type": "array"
                },
                "school_grade_low": {
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "type": "array"
                },
                "school_lea_code": {
                  "items": {
                    "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "type": "array"
                }
              },
              "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "secondary_number": {
            "items": {
              "type": "null"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "secondary_unit": {
            "items": {
              "type": "null"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "state": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "state_house_dist_name": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "state_house_dist_number": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "state_senate_dist_name": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "state_senate_dist_number": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "street": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suffix": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "timezone": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "utc_offset": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "zip": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "anniversary": {
        "properties": {
          "date": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "baptism": {
        "properties": {
          "church_id": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "birth_dd": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "birth_mm": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "birth_yyyy": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "church_attendance": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "likelihood": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "cohabiting": {
        "properties": {
          "confidence": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "likelihood": {
            "items": {
              "type": "null"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "dating": {
        "properties": {
          "bool": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "divorced": {
        "properties": {
          "bool": {
            "items": {
              "type": "null"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "likelihood_considering": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "education": {
        "properties": {
          "est_level": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "email": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "is_work_school": {
            "items": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "string": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "engaged": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "likelihood": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "est_income": {
        "properties": {
          "est_level": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "ethnicity": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "first_name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "formatted_birthdate": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "gender": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "head_of_household": {
        "properties": {
          "bool": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "home_church": {
        "properties": {
          "church_id": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "group_participant": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "is_coaching": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "is_giving": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "is_serving": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "membership_date": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "regular_attendee": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "hub_poid": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "insert_datetime_utc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "ip_address": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "string": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "last_name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "marriage_segment": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "string": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "married": {
        "properties": {
          "bool": {
            "items": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "middle_name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "miscellaneous": {
        "properties": {
          "attribute": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "value": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "name_suffix": {
        "type": "null"
      },
      "name_title": {
        "type": "null"
      },
      "newlywed": {
        "properties": {
          "bool": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "parent": {
        "properties": {
          "bool": {
            "items": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "likelihood_expecting": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "person_id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "phone": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "number": {
            "items": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "type": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "property_rights": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "string": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "psychographic_cluster": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "string": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "religion": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "string": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "religious_segment": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "string": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "separated": {
        "properties": {
          "bool": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "significant_other": {
        "properties": {
          "first_name": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "middle_name": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "name_suffix": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "name_title": {
            "type": "null"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "type": "null"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      },
      "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "target_group": {
        "properties": {
          "insert_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "string": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          },
          "suppressed_datetime_utc": {
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "array"
          }
        },
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "type": "object"
  },
  "type": "array"
}
```

Comment: Is there something special in your JSON format? For example, is every record on a new line, or does every record start with a line containing only `{`  and finishes with `}`, with indentation inside? If so, a trivial file parsing script could help :)

Comment: My code to split the JSON by each valid group is `csplit -n 6 -f <FILE_NAME>_ <FILE> '/\{(?:[^{}|(?R)])*\}/'` The `-f` just adds a prefix to the output files

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718175/how-to-split-a-csv-or-json-file-for-optimal-snowflake-ingestion, to split JSON/CSV and compress at the same time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the question whether Python or Node will be better for the task would be an opinion and we are not allowed to voice our opinions on Stack Overflow. You have to decide yourself what you have more experience in and what you want to work with - Python or Node.

If you go with Node, there are some modules that can help you with that task, that do streaming JSON parsing. E.g. those modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream

If you go with Python, there are streaming JSON parsers here as well:

- https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer
- https://github.com/danielyule/naya
- http://www.enricozini.org/blog/2011/tips/python-stream-json/

Answer (score 7):

Use this code in linux command prompt

```
split -b 53750k <your-file>
cat xa* > <your-file>
```

Refer to this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/28847/text-editor-to-edit-large-4-3-gb-plain-text-file

Comment: What is `xa*` supposed to be?

Comment: xa* are the default generated new splitted file names. you can do a ls -lrt

Comment: only if you want to take a glance of your JSON structure without further work with it because you'll lose the file structure

Answer (score 3):

consider to use jq to preprocessing your json files

it could split and stream your large json files

```
jq is like sed for JSON data - you can use it to slice 
and filter and map and transform structured data with 
the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you play with text.
```

see the [official documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808581/using-jq-how-can-i-split-a-very-large-json-file-into-multiple-files-each-a-spec?rq=1) for more.

extra: for your first questions jq is written by C, it's faster than python/node isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake has a [very special treatment for JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html) and if we understand them, it would be easy to draw the design.

1. JSON/Parquet/Avro/XML is considered as semi-structure data
2. They are stored as Variant data type in Snowflake.
3. While loading the JSON data into stage location, flag the strip_outer_array=true

   `copy into <table>
   from @~/<file>.json
   file_format = (type = 'JSON' strip_outer_array = true);`
4. Each row size can not exceed 16Mb compressed when loaded in snowflake.
5. Snowflake data loading [works well](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Loading-data-into-Snowflake-and-performance-of-large-joins) if the file size is split in the range of 10-100Mb in size.

Use the [utilities](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html) which can split the file based on per line and have the file size note more than 100Mb and that brings the power of parallelism as well as accuracy for your data.

As per your data set size, you will get around 31K small files (of 100Mb size).

- It means that the 31k parallel process run, however, it is not possible.
- So choose an x-large size warehouse (16 v-core & 32 threads)
- 31k/32 = (approximately) 1000 rounds
- This will not take more than a few minutes to load data based on your network bandwidth. Even if we think of 3sec per round, it may load the data in 50min.

Look at the warehouse configuration & [throughput](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Load-Terabytes-Into-Snowflake-Speeds-Feeds-and-Techniques) details and refer [semi-structured data loading best practice](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-concepts.html).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To split and compress at the same time with bash, resulting in files of ~100MB each:

```
cat bigfile.json  | split -C 1000000000 -d -a4 - output_prefix --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'
```

See more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718176/132438

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python3 with the following script:

```
import json

def split_json(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    chunk_size = len(data) // 3
    for i in range(3):
        with open(f"part{i}.json", 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(json.dumps(data[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size]))

file_path = input("Enter the file path of the JSON file: ")
split_json(file_path)
```

Comment: This script loads the entire initial json file in memory, which is why we are requesting to split the file in the first place: because it doesn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach that worked for me was this:

```py
json_file = <your_file>
chunks = 200
for i in range(0,len(json_file), chunks):
    print(json_file[i:i+chunks])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.